# Least common power

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Today I was trying to find a number that was both a power of 2 and a power of 3, that is two integers $m,n$ such that $2^m = 3^n$. These numbers seem not to exist, even if the equation was in the more general form $a^m = b^n$ where $a,b,m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $a \neq b^z \vee b \neq a^z \mid z \in \mathbb{N}$

Is there any rigorous proof which can be provided for my conjecture?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

How silly I am...

This is just a consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic. An integer will always have a definite number of prime factors, so, for example, $2^m$ will never be equal to $3^n$, since the two expressions are the factorization of two different numbers.

Comment: But you *can* have $a^n=b^m$ with neither $a$ nor $b$ a power of the other, e.g., $4^3=8^2$ even though 4 is not $8^z$ and 8 is not $4^z$ for any integer $z$. The correct conclusion from $a^n=b^m$ is that there is an integer $c$ such that $a=c^x$ and $b=c^y$ for some integers $x,y$.

Comment: Hence should my equation have instead the condition that $GCD(a,b)=1$? Because otherwise it would hold, as in $4^3=8^2$

Comment: $\gcd(a,b)=1$ is too strong a condition; $4^n=6^m$ doesn't have solutions even though $\gcd(4,6)\ne1$.

Comment: I see... What abot this: $\sqrt[c]{a} \neq \sqrt[d]{b}$ with $c,d \in \mathbb{N}$ If such a condition is not respected, it should turn out that $c = n$ and $d = m$. For example, while $4^m \neq 6^n$ because the condition is valid, instead $4^m = 8^n$ because $4=2^2$ and $8=2^3$; thus, as I said before, $m$ and $n$ should be respectively $3$ and $2$